# how to set particular path in the browser using wpf

Tags: c#

I have been designing `Wpf`. In that i want to set the particular path file in the browser.. say for example if click on the browser than it will direct u to that particular path instead of default path.

I am not able to do this. 
Any help is appreciated

**CODE**

```
// Create OpenFileDialog
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();          


dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";


Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
{

    string filename = dlg.FileName;
    FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;
 }
```

Comment: dlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\temp\";

Answer (score 0):

Set `InitialDirectory` before to `ShowDialog` , e.g. open "C:\Program Files":

```
// Create OpenFileDialog
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Program Files"; //       <-------       [Just added this line]

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
```